# EXCEPTION: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I'm getting this error in Google Chrome : EXCEPTION: $ is not defined.
Jquery and bootstrap are properly installed because there are no compilation errors.

My code here in TypeScript file :

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

I don't understand. Any fixes for this ?

Comment: Where do you have above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are declaring the variable `$`, you are over-riding the jQuery function.

The `JQueryStatic` is just the type of the variable. You have to link it properly.

Comment: And what is the correct way to import jquery in Angular 2 ?

Comment: you could use as     import * as jQuery from 'jquery';  This is in angular 2 cli... just replace wherever you would use $ with jQuery.

Comment: Haven't worked with Angular2, but something to help you start off. [Link](https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.7s76o8eh5)

Comment: Happens to the best of us.